# When does $2hxy + 2gx + 2fy + c =0$, with $h\neq 0$, represent a pair of straight lines?

Tags: conic-sections

For the standard conic equation in 2-D plane i.e 
$$ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 +2gx +2fy +c =0$$
If $a=b=0$ and $h\neq 0$, then the equation reduces to 
$$2hxy + 2gx + 2fy + c =0$$

> Under what conditions will the above equation represent a pair of straight lines?

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435685/condition-for-pair-of-straight-line-equation/3435841#3435841

Comment: Compare your equation with $$k(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta+p)(x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi+q)=0$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic#Discriminant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when $c = \frac{2fg}{h}$

Try a few examples

....................

Comment: @Sameernilkhan you did not finish your sentence. Also, instead of telling me what you were thinking, try a few examples.

Comment: I was thinking about conditions like C1) f=0 and c=0 then the equation becomes 2hxy + 2gx = 0 this implies x(hy + g) = 0 i.e. 2 real pair of straight lines. C2) g=0 and c=0 then the equation becomes 2hxy + 2fy = 0 this implies y(hx + f) = 0 i.e. 2 real pair of straight lines. C3) g=0, f=0 and c=0 then the equation becomes 2hxy=0 this implies x=0 and y=0  i.e. 2 real pair of straight lines. Are any more conditions possible?

Comment: I will surely try some examples if you explain the logic behind your condition i. e. c=fg/h.

Comment: I checked the example 6xy + 4x + 12y + 4 = 0. It represents a hyperbola.

Comment: @Sameernilkhan good, I mistakenly left off a factor of $2.$ Let's see, your $h=3$ $g=2$ $f=6$ so $\frac{2fg}{h}= \frac{24}{3} = 8$

Answer (score 1):

The equation  $2hxy + 2gx + 2fy + c =0$ is expected to be factorized as

$$ (px+q)(ty+s)=0$$

in order for it to present two lines. Match the coefficients to get,

$$pt = 2h, \>\>\> qt = 2g,\>\>\> sp=2f, \>\>\> qs = c$$

Then,

$$\frac pq =\frac hg = \frac {2f}c$$

Thus, the condition is $hc = 2fg$.

Comment: Thanks i got it.