# Prove that $x^2 + y^2 -1$ can't be a product of two linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove that $x^2 + y^2 -1$ can't be a product of two linear equations? 
I tried assuming that it is a product of $f(x,y) = ax + by +c$ and $g(x,y) = dx + ey +f$
and I finally found the following set of equations: 
$$ad = 1,$$
$$be = 1,$$
$$af + cd = 0,$$
$$bf + ce = 0,$$
$$cf = -1.$$
I should probably find a contradiction somewhere, but I am not sure how to solve this system and find this contradiction.

Comment: Where do your coefficients cone from? That is very crucial.

Comment: You are lacking an extra equation. Besides that, notice that the first two ones and the last one allow you to divide by $a,b,c,d,e,f$ whenever you want.

Comment: Well, no matter where the coeffs lie, the two lines intersect in a point $P$. If $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$, then you see that both $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ will be zero. *But* you see that both partials are never zero on the curve $F=0$.

Comment: I removed the [group-theory] tag as I could not see why it was relevant. (If you think it is relevant and want to add it again, then maybe comment with the justification?)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you multiplied and compared coefficients.

You should have six equations:

Coefficients of $x^2$ gives $ad=1$

Coefficients of $y^2$ gives $be=1$

### Coefficients of $xy$ gives $ae+bd=0$

Coefficients of $x$ gives $af+cd=0$

Coefficients of $y$ gives $bf+ce=0$

Constant terms gives $cf=-1$

You missed out the coefficients of $xy$

Use just the top three equations: $ad=1$ means that $a$ and $d$ are both positive or both negative. $be=1$ means that $b$ and $e$ are both positive or both negative.

That means that $ae$ and $bd$ have the same sign as each other.

But $ae+bd=0$ means that they can't have the same sign as each other unless they are both equal to zero, and that is your contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial solution for the case of $\mathbb R$:**

If $x^2 + y^2 -1= (ax + by +c)(dx + ey +f)$, then the equation
$$\tag{1}
x^2 + y^2 -1=0
$$
defines the union of two lines
$ax + by +c= 0$ and $dx + ey +f=0$. But we know that (1) defines a circle. We got a contradiction.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the coefficients are real?

Comment: If we don't know the base field then then I don't think it's clear that a circle is the union of two lines. In $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, in fact, $x^2+y^2-1=0$ is the same as $x+y-1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $af=-cd$ and $ce=-bf$ then $acef=bcdf$, and $ae=bd$ because $cf=-1$. But $(ae)^2=ad\cdot be=1$, so $ae\ne0$. As @DavidMolano notes, we have one more equation from the $xy$ coefficient. This coefficient is $ae+bd=2ae$, rather than $0$ as required.

Answer (score -1):

That means we've to prove that the given equation represents pair of straight lines. So, for a general second degree equation $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ to represent pair of straight line 
$$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
a&h&g\\
h&b&f\\
g&f&c
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

But here,$\Delta=-1\ne 0$. Hence the given expression can't be represented as product of two linear equations. [Check this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3435841).